# Cannot log out while using the Facebook SDK - Android

Tags: android, facebook, logout, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to learn this Facebook SDK for a couple days now and i seem to be stuck. I am building a basic application for a school project, when a user logs in for THE FIRST TIME, Facebook allows you to type in an email and your password and it signs you in. Once the user clicks "Log Out" i log out.. To my knowledge. Now when i go back to click sign on, it auto logs back into that last account. Doesn't give me an option to switch accounts. How can i fix this?

EDIT*** When i log in, then log out, then click log in again it says "You previously logged in to "APP NAME" with Facebook. Would you like to continue?"

The only options are cancel and continue. I can't even try to sign in with a different person! This is my issue, if anyone can solve it that would be awesome! in the mean time i will keep trying different things

```
package example.com.demo_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookActivity;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LoginButton fbButton;
CallbackManager callBackManager;

TextView nameBox;
TextView emailBox;
TextView idBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    fbButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    fbButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

    callBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    fbButton.registerCallback(callBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


            String user_id = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();



            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                    if (object != null)
                    {
                        displayInfo(object);
                    }
                    else {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "first_name, last_name, email, id");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });


}

public void displayInfo(JSONObject object)
{
    String first_name = "";
    String last_name = "";
    String email = "";
    String id = "";
    try {
        first_name = object.getString("first_name");
        last_name = object.getString("last_name");
        email = object.getString("email");
        id = object.getString("id");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    nameBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    emailBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    idBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtID);

    nameBox.setText(first_name+ " " +last_name);
    emailBox.setText(email);
    idBox.setText(id);

    ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);

    profilePictureView.setProfileId(id);



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can log out by using the [AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) class in the Facebook SDK.

So, to log out, just put an OnClickListener on your log out button and do this:

```
 public void logOut() {
        AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
        if (LoginManager.getInstance() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashSignIn.class));
    }
```

While you could have just used LoginManager.getInstance().logOut() to sign out, the next time you tried logging in, it would recognize your earlier account from the previous sign in attempt. So set the AccessToken to null to be treated as a fresh user.

Comment: The only issue is that there is technically no "Log out" button generated by me. The Facebook SDK auto generates the log out button once a user is signed in, so I'm not 100% sure on how to call that log out button they already have made

Comment: Listen up. Once the user signs in, you might have directed him to some other activity. Just add a button of your choice there and add on onClickListener on it. When you call the above mentioned method there, redirect the user to your login screen (just as shown in the above code). You would find that FB's log out button has changed back to login. This happend because you called LoginManager to set it so for you.

Comment: I tried setting the access token as null, but it still recognize my account that I logged in with previously. what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where I could not log in again as a different user and received the same message.

WHAT I TRIED:

1) Logging out without setting the AccessToken to null (**Didn't work**)

```
void logoutFacebook(){
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    // either finish() or startActivity() or any other app code
}
```

2) Setting the AccessToken to null before logging out (**Didn't work**)

```
void logoutFacebook(){
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null){
        AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
    }
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    // either finish() or startActivity() or any other app code
}
```

3) Removing the app from user's Facebook account (**Didn't work**)

```
void logoutFacebook(){
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null){
        AccessToken accessToken=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                new GraphRequest(accessToken
                        ,"/"+accessToken.getUserId()+"/permissions/"
                        ,null
                        ,HttpMethod.DELETE
                        ,new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
        AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
    }
    // either finish() or startActivity() or any other app code
}
```

WHAT WORKED:

Setting the LoginBehavior of fbButton to LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY right before calling registerCallback on fbButton.

```
fbButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY);
// now call registerCallback on fbButton
```

The default LoginBehavior of fbButton is LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK.

As per the facebook developers documentation on LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK and LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY

**NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK**

"*Specifies that login should attempt login in using the Facebook App, and if that does not work fall back to web dialog auth. This is the default behavior.*"

**WEB_VIEW_ONLY**

"*Specifies that only the web view dialog auth should be used.*"

For further reference go to -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/

This solution would probably require you to accommodate a small change in your Facebook sign in/up flow.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with Facebook SDK logout on Android. After much testing, discovered that the issue only occurs on Samsung phones. When logging in, the Facebook SDK would launch a webview, which caches the Facebook auth token. So, even if you logout on the SDK, the webview appears to keep the token. This is out of direct control of the Facebook SDK, but when login occurs, it detects an existing token and continues to login without further prompts. This appears to involve elements of @ravi's answer as a parameter for the [AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) can also specify "accessTokenSource", which can a webview.

If you clear the browser cache (Facebook appears to want to use Chrome if it's installed regardless of the default browser), then attempt to execute a Facebook login, you will then get the expected behaviour. Clearly, some more checks and balances are needed in the Facebook SDK to deal with lingering tokens.